# asp.net mvc LINQ, how to compare range of value in other range of value

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Comparing one range of value in other, if any value in the first range available in second range the result should be false and if totally first range is not available in second range and it's true.

```
range 1 = 1 to 100
range 2 = 1 to 200
range 3 = 180 to 300;
range 4 = 301 to 400;
```

> case 1 -> range1 / range2 = false //
>
> case 2 -> range3 / range2 = false //
>
> case 3 -> range4 / range 2 = true

how to implement this with mvc linq

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following approach:

```
var firstRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var secondRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 200);
var thirdRange = Enumerable.Range(180, 300);
var fourthRange = Enumerable.Range(301, 400);

var case1 = !firstRange.Any(element => secondRange.Contains(element));
var case2 = !thirdRange.Any(element => secondRange.Contains(element));
var case3 = !fourthRange.Any(element => secondRange.Contains(element));

Console.WriteLine(case1);
Console.WriteLine(case2);
Console.WriteLine(case3);
```

Comment: @SAR, let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qT70Y) is the link live demo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var firstRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        var secondRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 200);
        var thirdRange = Enumerable.Range(180, 300);
        var fourthRange = Enumerable.Range(301, 400);

        Console.WriteLine(!IsContainInRange(firstRange, secondRange));      
        Console.WriteLine(!IsContainInRange(thirdRange, secondRange));
        Console.WriteLine(!IsContainInRange(fourthRange, secondRange));
    }

    private static bool IsContainInRange(IEnumerable<int> range1, IEnumerable<int> range2)
    {
        return (from r1 in range1
                 join r2 in range2 on r1 equals r2 
                 select r1).Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer you question? @SAR

Comment: my dear, both are same answer but the first one was earlier, so based on that i accept as answer and i up voted you

Comment: It's okie. Have a nice day guy.